# Scala: line by line check for None, or check for exceptions at the end?

Tags: scala, exception

I have a case class `Application` that has some input ports, and each port has a name. Then I have another case class that assigns values to the ports of an application.

```
case class Port (id: ObjectId, name: String, PortType: String)
case class Application (id: ObjectId, ports: List[Port])
case class AppRun (appId: ObjectId, assignments: List[Assignment])
case class Assignment (portName: String, value: String, valueType: String)
```

I have the applications and their port information in a database, and I get as input an `AppRun`. I need to make a list of `PortValue` type (below) showing the value assigned to each port (and the matching is done on port names):

```
case class PortValue (portId: ObjectId, value: String)
```

There are a few things that may fail during this matching: application id is invalid, ports do not match, etc. It feels natural to me to write the straightforward algorithm and then catch all exceptions, but that seems Java-ish. On the other hand, I cannot think of a neat way of dealing with `Option`s , checking them one by one, which will obfuscate the code.

The question is how would you solve this Scala way?

---

EDIT: I need to send a proper message back when such a mismatch happens, like "application not found", etc.

Comment: Look at the 2nd and 3rd examples: http://nerd.kelseyinnis.com/blog/2013/11/12/idiomatic-scala-the-for-comprehension/

Comment: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

Comment: @Kolmar Thanks. I did in fact first write it with for-comprehension and it was very neat and small, but I also need to handle the error cases, and send a proper error message back.

Comment: Could you put come example of your straightforward error-checking code here? In general to keep track of the errors you have to use  `scala.util.Try`, or `Validation` from `scalaz` library instead of `Option`.

Comment: @al32 That's a good approach. If you make it into an answer I will accept it. Or I will write my own answer based on your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: When you write `case class Port {id: ObjectId, name: String, PortType: String}` you of course mean `case class Port(id: ObjectId, name: String, PortType: String)` right?

Comment: So from an higher point of view you basically need some `def func(appRun: AppRun): List[PortValue]` or something along this way? (It could then be a `Try[List[PortValue]]` or something like this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to deal with checking `Option`s one by one is to use a for-comprehension. And if you want to keep track of errors you can quite often replace `Option` with some class that does error-tracking. The common possibilities include:

- `scala.util.Try[T]`. `Try` is either a `Success(result)`, or a `Failure(error: Throwable)`. It is a built-in class in Scala, and it is simple to combine it with or replace it by `scala.concurrent.Future` if the need arises.
- `scala.util.Either[E, T]`. Creating a `Throwable` for every error may not be very efficient because of the need to build the stacktrace. So `Either` is useful if the error can be a simple `String` or some application-specific class without the stacktrace. The convention is to have a `Right(result)` or a `Left(error)`. The downsides are that it's not semantic to have 'right' mean 'success' and 'left' mean 'error', and when you use it in a for-comprehension or call e.g. `map` method on it, you have to specify whether you want `either.right` or `either.left`.
- `scalaz.\/[E, T]` This is the same as `Either`, but the default for `map` and for-comprehension is its right side (`\/-`). Also `scalaz` provides very useful functions `sequence` and `traverse` (see the code below).
- `scalaz.Validation[Errors, T]` or `scalaz.ValidationNel[E, T]`. Adds a very useful functionality of collecting all the errors, but has slight problems when used in for-comprehensions.

Here is some sample code for your problem, using `Try`:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def getApplication(appId: ObjectId): Option[Application] = ???

/** Convert Option to Try, using a given failure in case of None */
def toTry[T](option: Option[T])(failure: => Throwable): Try[T] =
  option.fold[Try[T]](Failure(failure))(Success(_))

/** Convert a List of Try to a Try of List.
  * If all tries in the List are Success, the result is Success.
  * Otherwise the result is the first Failure from the list */
def sequence[T](tries: List[Try[T]]): Try[List[T]] =
  tries.find(_.isFailure) match {
    case Some(Failure(error)) => Failure(error)
    case _ => Success(tries.map(_.get))
  }
def traverse[T, R](list: List[T])(f: T => Try[R]): Try[List[R]] =
  sequence(list map f)

def portValues(task: AppRun): Try[List[PortValue]] = for {
  app <- toTry(getApplication(task.appId))(
    new RuntimeException("application not found"))
  portByName = app.ports.map(p => p.name -> p).toMap
  ports <- traverse(task.assignments) { assignment =>
    val tryPort = toTry(portByName.get(assignment.portName))(
      new RuntimeException(s"no port named ${assignment.portName}"))
    tryPort.map(port => PortValue(port.id, assignment.value))
  }
} yield ports
```

Some considerations:

- Provided implementations of `toTry`, `sequence` and `traverse` are just a sample. For one, I'd define them in `implicit class`es to be able to call them like normal methods (e.g. `option.toTry(error)`, or `list.traverse(f)`).
- `traverse` can be implemented more effectively (stop after the first error is found).
- this `sequence` implementation would return only the first erroneous port.
- I prefer API like `def getApplication(id: ObjectId): Try[Application]` instead of an `Option` result, because you usually want to have the same error in every part of the code that calls it, and it may give different errors as well (e.g., id not found or network error). If you have `def getApplication(id: ObjectId): Application` that may throw an error you can simply wrap it in `Try`: `for { app <- Try(getApplication(id)) ...`

Comment: Thanks Kolmar. That looks indeed like what I need. My actual problem has a bit more stuff to match and read from the database, but I now have a good idea how to move forward. PS: I am using Salat to read from MongoDB, and it returns `Option`. But your `toTry` should do the trick.

Comment: Why do you create the `portByName` map, and not just use `find`?

Comment: @Mahdi I'm glad it helped. This answer is just some basic overview of the usual techniques for those kinds of problems. You are right, you can simply use `find`. It's just that I fixed a very similar performance problem last week (I had to replace find with xByName `Map`), so I optimized prematurely in this answer as well. But in my case the list had hundreds of items, for a small list of ports `find` should probably be faster.